# Monetizing an Android library?

Tags: android

I'm developing a library ( i.e. a JAR file that you put into the libs folder in eclipse ) which would extend surfaceView, which other people would hopefully use to make games.

I guess the best way to make any money off it would be to show banners on that surfaceview, right?

Maybe someone had similar experience? What advertising company would you suggest? admob, leadbolt? would they agree that I would integrate their sdk into my library ( not a finished app )?

Thanks!

Comment: Great question.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go with ads, personally. I would go with something like a subscription model (like what Corona SDK uses). Something like: this library is for $5/month. If you subscribe, great, you get access to the latest and greatest JARs (updated monthly). If not, no worries, you can use your hoary old version forever.

Comment: Selling a subscription isn't the best choice either, I guess, because charging someone $5/month would be way too little, if he makes a 1m+ downloads game OR it would be too much for a kid who just wants to play around with my library. Either way the library would appear on torrents in no time. :)
Another option I'm thinking about might be airpush...

Comment: Torrents are inevitable. Charge $50, then, if your library is that good. Corona SDK charges, and they do quite well -- albeit they have other benefits like faster compilation and daily builds